# Align buttons at the bottom of the panels

Tags: wordpress, yoothemes

How do I align these buttons at the button of these panels?

http://newsite.diningsix.dk/cater-test

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add some classes to the 'Read More' div.

```
<div class="uk-margin-top uk-position-bottom uk-margin-medium-left uk-margin-bottom">
      <a class="el-link uk-button uk-button-default" href="#" uk-scroll="">Read more</a>
</div>
```